# Fastest query to process data in small batches without repetition

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization, query

I have java app that is using MySQL in the backend. I have the following table:

`A = int, B = varchar, C = timestamp`

```
A | B   | C
1 | 100 | 2022-03-01 12:00:00
2 | 200 | 2022-03-01 12:00:01
3 | 100 | 2022-03-01 12:00:01
4 | 200 | 2022-03-01 12:00:02
5 | 600 | 2022-03-01 12:00:03
1 | 100 | 2022-03-01 12:00:06
5 | 700 | 2022-03-01 12:00:07
2 | 200 | 2022-03-01 12:00:08
9 | 100 | 2022-03-01 12:00:08
```

On every X seconds, query should be run, and it should process 5 records where column `C > LAST_PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP`. This `LAST_PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP` is updated after each run.

What I need is - I want to select these 5 rows, but not to include the rows if columns A and B are going to repeat in some fetches that are going to happen in the future.

Example: for table above:

First run - select 5

<strike>1 | 100 | 2022-03-01 12:00:00</strike> <-- NOT SELECTED SINCE IT IS IN 2nd RUN

<strike>2 | 200 | 2022-03-01 12:00:01</strike> <-- NOT SELECTED SINCE IT IS IN 2nd RUN

```
3 | 100 | 2022-03-01 12:00:01
4 | 200 | 2022-03-01 12:00:02
5 | 600 | 2022-03-01 12:00:03
```

Seconds run - select 5

```
1 | 100 | 2022-03-01 12:00:06
5 | 700 | 2022-03-01 12:00:07
2 | 200 | 2022-03-01 12:00:08
9 | 100 | 2022-03-01 12:00:08
```

In first run, we do not select `1|100` and `2|200`, since it will be selected in second run.

I already have some solutions for this, but selects are taking way too much time. The database is also huge - so I'm trying to find the fastest way to execute this. Which indices should I have to optimize this? Which kind of query?

What I tried:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM ( SELECT  A,B
            FROM  TABLE
            WHERE  C >= '2022-03-01 12:00:00'
            LIMIT  5
         ) a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  A,B
            FROM  TABLE
            WHERE  C >= '2022-03-01 12:00:00'
            LIMIT  5, 18446744073709551615
              ) b  ON (     a.A=b.A
                       AND  a.B=b.B
                      )
    WHERE  b.A IS NULL;
```

and also (this one is probably NOT OK, since it will select MAX of C even if not in first 5, so for my example, it would include `2 | 200 | 2022-03-01 12:00:08` inside of the first run - not what I need):

```
SELECT  A, B, MAX(C)
    FROM  TABLE
    WHERE  C >= '2022-03-01 12:00:00'
    GROUP BY  A, B ASC
    LIMIT  5;
```

Answer (score 0):

These would help your first attempt:

```
INDEX(C,A,B)
INDEX(A,B,C)
```

In order to figure out how to simplify or improve the query, start by tossing `b`.  It adds nothing but complexity to the question.  Think through the question with only `a` and `c`.

**More**

1. Pull 5 rows off the "input queue"
2. Identify "dups" (perhaps with `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NOT NULL`, or with `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )`
3. Store the non-dups (perhaps with `INSERT ...` in front of the `SELECT` in step 2)
4. push the dups back into the input queue (`DELETE` from the queue?)`

A "dup" is where A and B both match.

Comment: The `B` is there in order to filter the rows, since if `A` and `B` are showing up in some later row (so `B` has to be equal also), then I need to filter it out. Otherwise, if only `A`==`A` then I leave both rows in place.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic - Your example implied that the _combination_ of A and B acted like a single thing to uniquely identify the row.  I'm trying to transform the statement of the problem in order to focus on something simpler.

Comment: you can see from example that `1|100` is showing up twice in table, so it is not unique key. I think there is not other way except to try with the indexes as you said.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic - You eventually want to display each "1|100" row, correct?  So, as you imply, the "primary key" is more important than A and B when figuring out whether some row has already been displayed.

Comment: No, I wanted to filter duplicate rows that appear at the later dates. So use-case specific to my example: my program has memory to store only 5 rows at once. So when it selects the first 5 rows as in my example, I do not want to select rows that I will select in the next iteration (`1|100` will be selected also on 2nd run, so it should be skipped on first run - it will be anyway processed on 2nd run do delay it a bit).

Comment: "Duplicate" means "both A and B are duplicate", hence I can combine them when doing the dup test.  You have to look in the Table to see if "1|100" already exists?  That sounds like:  (1) grab exactly 5 rows, (2) remove any that already exist, (3) process the rest [possibly less than 5].

Comment: But, more significantly, any of those "dups" are kept in the array that cannot hold more than 5.  Hence, the next iteration will have 5 quicker than usual.

Comment: I made a stab at an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> I already have some solutions for this, but selects are taking way too much time.

Create an index by `(C,A,B)`. Then look for execution plan - if the index is not used then try to force its usage.

> What I tried

Excessively complex. Use

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE C >= '2022-03-01 12:00:00' 
ORDER BY C, A, B LIMIT 5;
```

> On every X seconds, query should be run, and it should process 5 records where column C > LAST_PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP. This LAST_PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP is updated after each run.

Not enough for deterministic processing.

Imagine that there are 6 rows with the same timestamp in C, which differs in A and B. Not more than 5 of them should be processed, and their timestamp is saved. Next run this timestamp is applied... but now I do not see the way to determine what rows of there 6 ones were processed already, and what other are to be processed now.

Add a column which will store a mark "this row was already processed". Use this column in the query which selects 5 rows for current processing.

Comment: Can you please tell me if this query is going to filter rows where `A` and `B` are duplicated? This one is only limiting to 5 results. Related to your other comment (deterministic) - you are right - here I would need to have `LIMIT = 5 + delta` where `delta = 1` in your example. I would find delta with separate query.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic *Can you please tell me if this query is going to filter rows where A and B are duplicated?* ??? Do you have another question? If so then create separate topic with it.

Comment: Not a new question, but the query you proposed me to use is not the same as the use-case I need. That is why I asked if I am missing something here, since I cannot see that it would filter rows having same A and B columns.

Comment: No, The question tells nothing about filtering the duplicates, and my query won't do this.